# vue v-on:click problem,actions do not work

Tags: vue.js

I am new to vuejs and I am trying to implement a javascript shopping cart,so I have this method,the output is a html table with some v-on:click actions that do not work,what is wrong

```
 <div v-html="str"></div>
            <div v-html="total"></div>
            <div v-html="count"></div>
```

---

```
 var vm = new Vue({
            el: '#vue_det',
            data: {
                
                str:"",
                total:0,
                count:0

            },
            methods: {
displaycart: function ()
                    {
                        var cartArray = shoppingCart.listCart();
    
                        var output = "<table>";
                        for (var i in cartArray) {
                            output += "<tr>"
                                    + "<td>" + cartArray[i].name + "</td>"
                                    + "<td>(" + cartArray[i].price + ")</td>"
                                    + "<td><div class='input-group'><button v-on:click=minusitem('" + cartArray[i].name + "') class='minus-item input-group-addon btn btn-primary'  >-</button>"
                                    + "<input type='number' class='item-count form-control' data-name='" + cartArray[i].name + "' value='" + cartArray[i].count + "'>"
                                    + "<button  v-on:click=plusitem('" + cartArray[i].name + "') class='plus-item btn btn-primary input-group-addon'  >+</button></div></td>"
                                    + "<td><button v-on:click=deleteitem('" + cartArray[i].name + "') class='delete-item btn btn-danger'  >X</button></td>"
                                   
                                    + "<td>" + cartArray[i].total + "</td>"
                                    + "</tr>";
                        }
                        output +="</table>";
                         this.str=output;
                         this.total=shoppingCart.totalCart()
                         this.count=shoppingCart.totalCount()
                       // $('.show-cart').html(output);
                      //  $('.total-cart').html(shoppingCart.totalCart());
                       // $('.total-count').html(shoppingCart.totalCount());
                    }
                },
```

Comment: You should not be trying to insert html with jquery in vue, you should either use vue or jquery, there's really no reason for both; this should all probably be converted to Vue components and displayed using vue state

Comment: v-html content is "interpreted as plain HTML - data bindings are ignored".

Comment: I put jquery staff in comments,what should I do about v-html.
How can I add html?

Comment: this is so wrong...You should go and read the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/index.html) first...

Comment: using v-html eliminates the data-binding features in those elements. I'm really curious why u have to write vue this way instead of writing the template directly where it should be

Comment: Ok ,I tried to convert a cart from jquery to vuejs but this is the wrong way as I understand.Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make this code for my shopping cart

```
<div id="vue_det">
            <div id="products">
                <p>
                    Orange,pricε:20 <a href="#" v-on:click = "addItemToCart('orange',20,1)">Add</a>  
                </p>
                <p>
                    Paok,pricε:22 <a href="#" v-on:click = "addItemToCart('paok',22,1)">Add</a>  
                </p>
            </div>   


            <div v-for="entry in listCart()" class="entry">{{ entry.name }}
                <button v-on:click=removeItemFromCart(entry.name) >-</button>
                <input type='number'  v-model.number="entry.count"  >
                <button  v-on:click=addItemToCart(entry.name)>+</button>
                <button v-on:click=removeItemFromCartAll(entry.name)   >X</button>
                {{entry.total}}
            </div>
            <div>Total:{{totalCart()}}</div>
            <div>Totalcount:{{totalCount()}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

---

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#vue_det',
    data: {
        item:
                {
                    name: "",
                    price: 0,
                    count: 0
                },
        cart: []

    },
    methods: {
        addItemToCart: function (name, price, count) {
            for (var item in this.cart) {
                if (this.cart[item].name === name) {
                    this.cart[item].count++;
                   this.saveCart();
                    return;
                }
            }
            var item = {};
            item.count = count;
            item.price = price;
            item.name = name;
            this.cart.push(item);
              this.saveCart();
        },
         saveCart: function ()
    {
        sessionStorage.setItem('shoppingCart', JSON.stringify(this.cart));
        return;

    },
    // Load cart
    loadCart: function () {
        this.cart = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('shoppingCart'));
    },
    setCountForItem : function (name, count) {
        for (var i in this.cart) {
            if (this.cart[i].name === name) {
                this.cart[i].count = count;
                this.saveCart();
                break;
            }
        }
    },
    removeItemFromCart : function (name) {
        for (var item in this.cart) {
            if (this.cart[item].name === name) {
                this.cart[item].count--;
                if (this.cart[item].count === 0) {
                    this.cart.splice(item, 1);
                }
                this.saveCart();
                break;
            }
        }
        this.saveCart();
    },
   removeItemFromCartAll :function (name) {
        for (var item in this.cart) {
            if (this.cart[item].name === name) {
                this.cart.splice(item, 1);
                this.saveCart();
                break;
            }
        }
       //this.saveCart();
    },
    clearCart : function () {
        cart = [];
        this.saveCart();
    },
    totalCount : function () {
        var totalCount = 0;
        for (var item in this.cart) {
            totalCount += this.cart[item].count;
        }
        return totalCount;
    },
    totalCart : function () {
        var totalCart = 0;
        for (var item in this.cart) {
            totalCart += this.cart[item].price * this.cart[item].count;
        }
      
        return Number(totalCart.toFixed(2));
    },
    listCart : function () {
        var cartCopy = [];
        for (i in this.cart) {
           //item =cart[i];
            itemCopy = {};
           for (p in this.cart[i]) {
               // itemCopy[p] = this.cart[i][p];
                itemCopy[p] = this.cart[i][p];
                

             }
            itemCopy.total = Number(this.cart[i].price * this.cart[i].count).toFixed(2);
            cartCopy.push(itemCopy)
        }
        return cartCopy;
    },
    
    
    },
   

    created: function () {
        if (sessionStorage.getItem("shoppingCart") != null) {
            this.loadCart();
        }
    },
})
        </script>
```